# The set of convergence of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $F_n :E \to \mathbb{ R} $ be a sequence of measurable functions. Let $$E^*= \{ x\in E : F_n  \text{ is convergent } \}$$ Is the set $E^*$ measurable?

To solve this, I need to understand the relation between the set $E^*$ and the functions $F_n$. They are strongly related, but how can I express this relation in terms of sets and measure?

Comment: Capitals are not well received. It associates with shouting. Avoid them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I preassume that $E^{*}:=\{x\in E: (F_n(x))_n\text{ is a convergent sequence}\}$ and mention that $\mathbb N$ denotes the set of positive integers in this answer.

Then for $x\in E$:

$$x\in E^{*}\iff\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\forall r,s\in\mathbb{N}\left[r,s\geq n\implies\left|F_{r}\left(x\right)-F_{s}\left(x\right)\right|<\frac{1}{k}\right]$$
So if $\mathbb N_n$ denotes $\{n,n+1,\dots\}$ then:

$$E^{*}=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{\left(r,s\right)\in\mathbb{N_n}^{2}}\left\{ x\in E:\left|F_{r}\left(x\right)-F_{s}\left(x\right)\right|<\frac{1}{k}\right\}$$

The sets $\left\{ x\in E:\left|F_{r}\left(x\right)-F_{s}\left(x\right)\right|<\frac{1}{k}\right\} $
are measurable and we are dealing with countable unions and intersections.

So $E^{*}$ is measurable.

Comment: but what is that third intersection .. I did not get it ..

Comment: What intersection? The one with index $(r,s)$?

Comment: I guess it's a measurable set but is it the same sequence of  functions my sequence is Fn(x)  what is (Fn(x))n

Comment: You are speaking of a sequence, but $F_n(x)$ on its own *is no sequence*. It is nothing more than one value of function $F_n$. That's why I preassumed that you were taking about the sequence $F_1(x),F_2(x)\dots$ (this for every $x$) wich can be denoted as $(F_n(x))_n$. Also in your title you are calling (wrongly) $F_n$ a sequence of measurable functions. The right notation for a sequence of functions is $(F_n)_n$.

Comment: @drhab May i ask why are the sets $\{x\in E: |F_{r}(x) - F_{s}(x)| < \frac{1}{k} \}$ measurable?

Comment: @teotheo If $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions then also functions like $f+g$ and $f-g$ and $|f|$ are measurable (so also $|f-g|$, so that the sets that you mention are measurable). If you wonder why then you might ask a question about that (eventually with link to this question). It goes too far to treat this in a comment.

Comment: @drhab Your appealing to Cauchy sequences is reasonable, but I don't understand why you let $n$ run over all of $\mathbb{N}$ in the union.

Comment: @Steve Working out the RHS of the equivalence that starts with $\forall k\exists n\dots$ we get automatically $\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\dots$. Do you have an alternative?