# questions about measurable sets.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

and $(f_n)_n$ a sequence of measurable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (where $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the Borel's $\sigma$-algebra).

Prove that the following two sets are measurable 
$$A=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=+\infty \}, \qquad B=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\ |(f_n(x))_n\text{ is bounded}\}.$$

Comment: Not that it changes this particular question, but it is generally dangerous to assume that there is a "usual" sigma-algebra on the reals.

Comment: What are your own ideas or attempts?

Comment: There must be something missing in the definition of $A.$ Do you mean those $x$ where the limit exists as a real number?

Comment: I think you are missing something in your definition of $A$.

Comment: The domain of the $f_n$ is said to be the measurable space $E$, yet the argument in the displayed formulas for $A$ and $B$ is in $\mathbb{R}$.  Are we to assume that $E\subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @ForgotALot , sorry guys, I corrected it now.

Comment: Set $A$ is - in spite of your edit - still not well defined. Do you mean $A:=\{x\in E\mid (f_n(x))_n\text{ is converging}\}$?

Comment: Same comment after your second edit. If set $A$ is defined as I suggested in my former comment then have a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1515892/75923).

Comment: @drhab can u take another look  now ?

Comment: @Justpassingby from what I have experienced so far it seems to be very common in the literature not to mention that $\mathbb R$ is equipped with the Borel $\sigma$ algebra when talking about measurable real valued functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbb N$ denote the set of positive integers.

---

The following statements are equivalent:

- $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\left(x\right)=+\infty$
- $\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\exists k\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\geq k\; f_{n}\left(x\right)\geq m$
- $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty}\left\{ y\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_{n}\left(y\right)\geq m\right\} $

This tells us that: $$A:=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\left(x\right)=+\infty\right\} =\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty}\left\{ y\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_{n}\left(y\right)\geq m\right\} $$

The RHS is measurable because for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the set $\left\{ y\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_{n}\left(y\right)\geq m\right\} $
is measurable.

---

The following statements are equivalent:

- $\left(f_{n}\left(x\right)\right)_{n}$ is bounded
- $\exists m\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\; f_{n}\left(x\right)\leq m$
- $x\in\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{ y\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_{n}\left(y\right)\leq m\right\} $

This tells us that: $$B:=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid\left(f_{n}\left(x\right)\right)_{n}\text{ is bounded}\right\} =\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{ y\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_{n}\left(y\right)\leq m\right\} $$

The RHS is measurable because for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the set $\left\{ y\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_{n}\left(y\right)\leq m\right\} $
is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Write $f(x)=inf f_{n}(x)$. Note that $$\{x\in X:f(x)\leq\alpha\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x\in X:f_{n}(x)\leq\alpha\}$$
Thus $f$ is measurable. Similarly, $sup f_{n}(x)$ is measurable. It follows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x)=\lim\ inf (f_{n}(x))=sup_{n\geq1}\{inf_{m\geq n} f_{m}(x)\}$$
is measurable.

Comment: this was not the question at all.

Comment: This is obvious. I just showed that A is measurable.

Comment: I changed $A$ a bit.