# Prove that the given set $E_0$ is measurable

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions defined on a measurable set $E$ .Define $E_0$ to be the set of points $x$ in $E$  at which $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges .Is the set $E_0$ measurable?

**My try**:

Let $f(x)=\lim _{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$

$E_0=\{x\in E:f_n(x)  \mbox{converges}\}$

To show that $E_0$ is measurable consider the set $\{x:f(x)>c\}$ for any $c\in \Bbb R$.

If $f_n(x)$ converges for some $a\in E_0$ then  $f(a)=\lim _{n\to \infty} f_n(a)$ then $|f_n(a)-f(a)|<\frac{1}{n}\forall n\in \Bbb N$

So $f(a)-\frac{1}{n}<f_n(a)<f(a)+\frac{1}{n};\forall n\in \Bbb N$

Then $\{x:f(x)>c\}=\cap_{{n\in \Bbb N}}[\{x:f_n(x)>f(a)-\frac{1}{n}\}\cap \{x:f_n(x)<f(a)+\frac{1}{n}\}]$
which is measurable as $f_n$ is measurable  and measurable sets form a $\sigma-$ algebra.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: How do you define $f$ on the complement of $E_0$?

Comment: $A=\cap_{{n\in \Bbb N}}[\{x:f_n(x)>f(a)-\frac{1}{n}\}\cap \{x:f_n(x)<f(a)+\frac{1}{n}\}]$, $A$ is the is the set of $x$ where $f_n$ converges to $c$ where $c=f(a)$, it does not give you all $x$ such that the sequence converges

Comment: I'd suggest thinking of $E_0$ as the set of $x$s for which $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: if you know that $\limsup f_n$ and $\liminf f_n$ are measurable functions then $E_0=[ \limsup f_n=\liminf f_n]$$

Comment: Your try is not correct. E.g. convergence $f_n(a)\to f(a)$ does not guarantee that $|f_n(a)-f(a)|\leq\frac1{n}$ for each $n$. Have a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1515892/75923)

Answer (score 0):

Let $E_{c}$ be the set in question.

Then note that $E_{c} = \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{p \in \mathbb{N}} \{E: |f_{N+p} - f_{N}| < \frac{1}{m} \}$.