# Prove that there must exist a measurable function $f$ on E and {$f_n$} converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X,R,\mu)$ is a measure space,{$f_n$} is a sequence of measurable function on E.If {$f_n$} is convergence almost everywhere on E. Prove that there must exist a measurable function $f$ on E and {$f_n$} converges to $f$ almost everywhere.
If $(X,R,\mu)$ is a complete measure space, I can find a measurable set $E_1$,where $\mu(E-E_1)=0$ and {$f_n$} convergent to a measurable function $f_1$ on $E_1$.We set $$f =
\begin{cases}
f_1,  & \text{if $x\in E_1$} \\
0, & \text{if $x\in E-E_1$ }
\end{cases}$$
So $f$ is the measurable function on E.However,if $(X,R,\mu)$ is only a measurable space,how to prove $E_1$ is a measurable set.

Comment: If every $f_n$ is measurable then $\{x\mid (f_n(x))_n\text{ converges}\}$ is a measurable set, and you can take $E_1$ as that set. For a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1515892/75923).

Comment: Sorry, what is $(f_n(x))_n)$, I did not get it.

Comment: It is the sequence  $f_1(x),f_2(x),\dots$.

Comment: @drhab For $$x\in E^{*}\iff\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\forall r,s\in\mathbb{N}\left[r,s\geq n\implies\left|F_{r}\left(x\right)-F_{s}\left(x\right)\right|<\frac{1}{k}\right]$$ It seems that on the left hand,$f_n(x)$ is convergence while on the right hand $f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergence.

Comment: @drhab Sorry,I made a mistake minuates ago, I think I get it now.